# Is there a cross-platform method of packaging many icons into one file?

Tags: icons, archiving, cross-platform

I'm trying to find a method of packaging/archiving many .ico icon files (or another cross-platform equivalent) for use with a program for its multiple file type associations.

On windows, I could package them into a .dll or into the .exe file itself, but those are both windows only.

Is there an equivalent that will work on Windows, Mac and Linux, so I don't have to supply individual icon files?

Comment: @Spiff I'm meaning readable natively by the OS as an icon for a file manager. Windows won't read a tar that way

Comment: Oh I see. You'll just need to package them in the normal native way for each platform. For macOS, they go in your .app bundle's Resources directory. For any OS, you can find a way to build them into the data segment of that OS's native executable binary format.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no cross-platform way to store file type associations and the relevant file type icons for an app. There are plenty of cross-platform ways to package multiple icons into a single file, but none of them will automatically communicate to each OS's native file manager which icon goes with which file type for which app. The way apps communicate their file type associations and corresponding icons to the native file manager(s) differs from platform to platform.